# How to select a check button on the menu by default in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

How to turn the check button value in the menu to checked? I searched the internet, tried many random values but still I am not getting the answer.

```
    view_menu.add_checkbutton(label=" Find ", background="#0084BA", foreground="white", 
    activebackground='black', font=('Calibri', 12), compound='left')
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1.You can give a variable. If you set it to 1, the Checkbutton will be selected.

```
var = tkinter.IntVar(value = 1)
view_menu.add_checkbutton(label=" Find ", background="#0084BA", variable=var)
```

2.If you have direct access to the checkbox, you can also use the set() method:

```
box = Checkbutton(label=" Find ", background="#0084BA", foreground="white")
box.set(1)
```